# Regex: How to search for identifiers \w that do not contain 2 consecutive underscores

Tags: regex, identifier

I tried `"[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)+"` in order to find identifiers consisting of '_'-chained alnum components, starting with a letter and containing no lower cases like e.g. "ID_RED", "NO_ENTRY_PERMITTED", "THIS_IS4YOU_ALL". I do not want to catch "THINKING__NO" or "4YOU_AND_ME".

The mistake seems to be in the second part `"(_[A-Z0-9]+)+"`; it's at least not greedy as expected but yields _RED, _ENTRY, _IS4YOU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `[A-Z0-9_]*` part that can match 0 or more consecutive `_` chars. Your pattern is not anchored anyhow, so it can find partial matches in longer words, too.

You may use

```
\b[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(?:_[A-Z0-9]+)+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vey6Si/3)

**Details**:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter
- `[A-Z0-9]*` - 0+ uppercase letters or digits
- `(?:_[A-Z0-9]+)+` - 1 or more occurrences of `_` and then 1+ uppercase letters or digits
- `\b` - word boundary